# Can we intercept outgoing http requests from a node js app using middleware like "Intercepting outgoing servlet http requests in java"

Tags: node.js, laravel-middleware

I have several http requests in my node.js app. I want to intercept the outgoing http requests and add a token in the header without changing the code in the app by introducing the interception code as an middleware or wrapper as in java

Comment: You don't need to intercept the outgoing request.  You can use normal middleware to intercept the incoming request and then use `res.setHeader()` to set a header on the response that will be added to whatever else the response is.

Comment: Do I have to add res.setHeader() line in each request?